# htaccess rewrite rule working for www version but not for non-www version

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase / 

# This will redirect all versions to http://www.sitename.com version
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.sitename.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I open page `www.sitename.com/rrule`, it is working properly but if I access same page without www like this `sitename.com/rrule`, it just redirects to `index.php` page that I set as different rule.

```
RewriteRule ^rrule$ ./user/rrule.php [L,NC]
```

Same issue is with page with query string.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ ./user/rrule_one_var.php?oneid=$1 [L,NC]
```

I want to make so rules work for both versions of website (www and without www).

Answer (score 0):

Force URL as www when accessing non-www cases. So set your URL as be unique with www version.

Case 1:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.yoursite\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Alternate Case :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And add your rewrite conditions below. Now your problem will be solved.

Comment: it makes no difference in result. When we access sitename.com, it goes to www.sitename.com but it is not working for rewrite rule I mentioned in my question.